Flutter Provider Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Builder Widget. In Floating Action Button
I'm encountering an issue in my Flutter app where I'm getting the error message: "Error: Could not find the correct Provider<GroupService> above this Builder Widget." I've wrapped my Home widget with ChangeNotifierProvider<GroupService>, but I'm still facing this issue.
Home.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:attendance_app/services/group_service.dart';
import 'package:attendance_app/components/attendance_group_cards.dart';
import 'package:attendance_app/components/add_group_dialog.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<GroupService>(
      create: (context) => GroupService(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(
            'ATTENDANCE APP',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue[500],
        ),
        body: Consumer<GroupService>(
          builder: (context, groupService, child) {
            return AttendanceGroupCards(
              groupService: groupService,
              urduStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Jameel_Noori',
                fontSize: 24,
              ),
              englishStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Lato',
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () => _showAddGroupDialog(context),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          label: const Text("Add Group"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue[500],
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          splashColor: Colors.white10,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showAddGroupDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AddGroupDialog(
          onAddGroup: (String groupName) {
            Provider.of<GroupService>(context, listen: false)
                .addGroup(groupName);
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: Text("Added $groupName"),
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

group_service.dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'; 
import 'package:attendance_app/models/attendance_data.dart';

class GroupService extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Group> _groups = [
   
  ];
  List<Group> get groups => List.unmodifiable(_groups);

  //

  void addGroup(String groupName) {
    Group newGroup = Group(
      groupId: DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
      groupName: groupName,
    );
    _groups.add(newGroup);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteGroup(String groupId) {
    _groups.removeWhere((group) => group.groupId == groupId);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void editGroup(String groupId, String newGroupName) {
    _groups.forEach((group) {
      if (group.groupId == groupId) {
        group.groupName = newGroupName;
      }
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }
}




I wrapped my Home widget with ChangeNotifierProvider to provide the GroupService throughout the widget tree. However, when I attempted to access the GroupService using Provider.of(context) within a method called _showAddGroupDialog(BuildContext context), I encountered the error message: "Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Builder Widget."
To resolve this issue, I ensured that the Home widget is within the subtree where the provider is defined, and I confirmed that the context used to access the provider is within this subtree. Additionally, I verified that there are no conditional statements or error boundaries interfering with the provider initialization.
Despite these efforts, the error persisted. I'm seeking insights or suggestions on why this error might be occurring and how I can resolve it.
According to a similar  Question  it says..
When you use showDialog() method, the inner BuildContext and outer BuildContext can get tangled up which implies potential misbehaviors for your UI. To clear things out, you should declare your common class at the beginning of build(), then reuse it within the AlertDialog (which is also a best practice for reusing code):
So I tried this and it also does not seem to work
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:attendance_app/services/group_service.dart';
import 'package:attendance_app/components/attendance_group_cards.dart';
import 'package:attendance_app/components/add_group_dialog.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<GroupService>(
      create: (context) => GroupService(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(
            'ATTENDANCE APP',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue[500],
        ),
        body: Consumer<GroupService>(
          builder: (context, groupService, child) {
            return AttendanceGroupCards(
              groupService: groupService,
              urduStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Jameel_Noori',
                fontSize: 24,
              ),
              englishStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Lato',
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () => _showAddGroupDialog(
              context,
              Provider.of<GroupService>(context,
                  listen: false)), // Pass the context of Home widget
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          label: const Text("Add Group"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue[500],
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          splashColor: Colors.white10,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _showAddGroupDialog(BuildContext context, groupListModel) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AddGroupDialog(
          onAddGroup: (String groupName) {
            groupListModel.addGroup(groupName);
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: Text("Added $groupName"),
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


